# Como podria ingresar esos 2 arrays desde consola, independientemente del tamaño?

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

    
x_d = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
y_d = np.array([0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.6, -0.8, -1, -0.9, -0.4])
    
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
    
for i in range(1, 7):
    
    y_est = np.polyfit(x_d, y_d, i)
    plt.subplot(2,3,i)
    plt.plot(x_d, y_d, 'o')

    plt.plot(x_d, np.polyval(y_est, x_d))
    plt.title(f'Polynomial order {i}')
    print(y_est)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

He intentado de varias maneras, pero no se si haya una funcion recursiva que lo haga. Para algo de contexto, el programa es de regresion lineal, usando la libreria de numpy. Pero necesito meter los datos desde consola y posteriormente, subirlos a una pagina web.

Comment: quieres introducir los array desde la consola pero con un limite de 10 elementos?

Comment: No me hice entender, quiero meter los array desde consola, sin limites en el array.

Comment: haaa ya, ahora elabora la respuesta

Comment: Ya lo edito, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno tu problema es tan facil como poner un `input()` para que ingrese los valores separados por coma `,` y luego convertir esos valores a `float` para ser procesados a un `numpy.array`

Lo único que hay que reemplazar las líneas donde inicializas las variables por estas.

```py
#pedimos los datos
x_d = input("Ingrese los valores del array x: ").split(',')
y_d = input("Ingrese los valores del array y: ").split(',')
```

El input siempre te devolverá un string pues el programa no sabe diferenciar los tipo de datos, luego usamos el método `split()` para separar la cadena según la coma `,` y regresa una lista con los elementos separados.

Ahora lo que tenemos es algo como esto `["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]`, como vemos tenemos los elementos pero están como un string por lo que hay que convertirlo, eso lo hacemos con ayuda de un ciclo `for`, en mi caso usare una compresión de lista para abreviar el trabajo.

```py
#convertimos el string a float y lo ponemos en un np.array
x_d = np.array([float(x) for x in x_d]) #0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
y_d = np.array([float(y) for y in y_d]) #0,0.8,0.9,0.1,-0.6,-0.8,-1,-0.9,-0.4
```

**Con ciclo `for` tradicional**
Esto seria el equivalente con un ciclo `for` normal

```
val_x = []
val_y = []

for x in x_d:
    x = float(x)
    val_x.append(x)

for y in y_d:
    y = float(y)
    val_y.append(y)

x_d = val_x
y_d = val_y
```

Como ves es un poco mas largo pero da el mismo resultado, sin embargo la compresión de lista es mucho mas rápido, lo que podría significar un gran cambio al procesar vario datos.

**Prueba**

```
Ingrese los valores del array x: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Ingrese los valores del array y: 0,0.8,0.9,0.1,-0.6,-0.8,-1,-0.9,-0.4
```

Y esto dará el resultado esperado.

Comment: Que genio, andaba con ese problema todo el dia porque precisamente habia intentado la solucion de usar el .split, pero segun lei lo convertia a string, y eso me daba problemas para operar las funciones usando numpy. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: lo que te devuelve un `input()` es string pues el programa no sabe diferenciar, el `split()` se usa para separar una cadena según lo que se le pase luego emplee una compresión de lista para convertir de string a float. ahora edito la respuesta añadiendo explicacion

Comment: Lo que si me quedo es una duda, si quiero hacer lo mismo con una matriz de mayor tamaño (mas dimensiones) como separo en el input una dimension de otra?

Comment: se puede en una línea xd=np.array([float(x) for x in input("Ingrese los valores separados por espacios: ").split()])

Comment: Mm creo que no entendi bien la sintaxis. Como haria para ingresar digamos, 
(1,2,3
3,2,1
1,1,1)

Comment: @Alejandro puedes ingresar cualquier numero de elementos, si quieres ingresar ambas matrices en un solo input, cambiaria la cosa

Comment: @Christian Necesito es meter una matriz de mas dimensiones, no una 1*X. Si digamos quiero meter una matriz 2x2, como haria el espacio para añadir la segunda fila de numeros?

Comment: @Alejandro una matriz de `x*n` para `x` y otra de `y*n` para `y`?

Comment: Si. Siendo X el numero de datos que  tendria X y lo mismo con Y. Para añadir matrices cuadradas.

Comment: te puedo decir como hacerlo pero no se como implementarlo para el grafico, te sugiero que hagas otra pregunta explicándolo mejor, pues esto ya no tiene relación  con la pregunta y respuesta actuales

Comment: Entendido, ahi cree el post.

Comment: @Alejandro ok en un rato lo veo, voy a cenar